# PhoneGap external hosts wildcard

Tags: javascript, cordova, connection, wildcard, whitelist

I'm using a js library inside a PhoneGap application for iPhone. I don't know what other external sites my js library contacts, so I need a way of whitelisting all connections, just for testing. How do I do that?

My app just silently fails, it doesn't continue from where the library is initiated.
(when I run the app in a browser it works perfectly)

Comment: A quick note: your app will be rejected by the app store because of this dependency... You MUST include some sort of notification to the user that the app needs a connection in order to work. I HIGHLY recommend that you include your jQuery mobile stuff in your www folder.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try setting the value of the `ExternalHosts` property in Phonegap.plist to `*`

Comment: Done, looks like this (http://cl.ly/0N3W0s1X27453T2V0V2x) in the editor. Have some other whitelistings as well, but they were added before and works as they should

Answer (score 1):

i think you need to add the domain names to **PhoneGap.plist** file or **Cordova.plist**.

And your App is running fine in browser. So in Browser source-code you can check-out for the external links present in your code.

Which ever file you want to access/link through internet, that server domain you need to add in plist file. suppose i have added jquery like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4.1/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4.1/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.js"></script>
```

now i need to add `code.jquery.com` in PhoneGap.plist-> ExternalHosts array as string.

Comment: The thing is that I don't know which external hosts that will be contacted. I've already modified Phonegap.plist to allow the library in the first place. (and the source of the library isn't readable "enough")