# GWT PhoneGap RPC - status exception 0

Tags: java, gwt, cordova, mgwt

RPC call runs successfully in my localhost and when i pushed the project with phonegap integration and tested out in android emulator `Rpc call fails and throws status exception 0 or gwt rpc Object not found-404`. I did refer tutorial from [gwt phonegap rpc-Daniel](http://blog.daniel-kurka.de/2012/04/gwt-rpc-with-phonegap-revisited.html) and did changes like mentioned in above tut:

```
final ServiceDefTarget serv=(ServiceDefTarget)checkuser;
Window.alert(serv.getServiceEntryPoint());
PhonegapUtil.prepareService(serv,"http://myip:8888/plac/reg","reg");
```

Where `plac` is my project space where it resides and `reg` is URLPattern. I end up either with `status code 0` exception or `StatusCodeException 404 Notfound`.

Please let me know where I am wrong.

Web.xml:

```xml
<!-- Servlets -->
<servlet>
<servlet-name>Register</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.plac.server.Register</servlet-class>
</servlet>  
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Register</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/plac/reg</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Register</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/plac/signup</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: can you post the relevant parts of your web xml?

Comment: @DanielKurka I have updated the relavent   web.xml

Answer (score 2):

Your code needs to look like this:

```
PhonegapUtil.prepareService(serv,"http://myip:8888/plac/","reg");
```

The first parameter is the url to your module in your case this should be:

```
"http://myip:8888/plac/"
```

and the relative url of your service (to your module)

```
"reg"
```

Comment: I did change the method,like you specified,but still i receive Status Code Exception 0

Comment: where are your module files located (which url)?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add pattern:

```
<!-- Servlets -->
<servlet>
<servlet-name>Register</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.plac.server.Register</servlet-class>
</servlet>  
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Register</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/plac/reg</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Register</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/plac/reg/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

You may have a / appended to you URL. In that case you'll get a 404.

Do you run in an phonegap environment?

If yes ensure to allow a wildcart access to server: [PhoneGap external hosts wildcard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10328630/phonegap-external-hosts-wildcard)

Comment: yes i did make the changes and also defined the permission for my ip in <access origin="http://my ip:888*"/> in cordova.xml(phonegap).. badly i end up with  com.googlewebclient.rpc  404 Object  not found !

Comment: a 404 is better than a 0, because you have connected the server.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem which kept me struggling for lots of hours. At some point I came across the solution which looks a bit different from the one above:

When you call `http://myip:8888/plac/reg` from a browser it should return 
`HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method GET is not supported by this URL`, if it refers to the desired service. 
Otherwise the url is missing something - looking at the resources you provided I am guessing the name of your GWT web app is missing.

Try `http://myip:8888/YourAppName/plac/reg` whereas `http://myip:8888/YourAppName` is the url you use to pull up your GWT app from a browser.

So, the code should look like this:
`PhonegapUtil.prepareService(serv,"http://myip:8888/YourAppName/plac/","reg");`

Hope this helps.